# Node red MongoDB Connection Error: failed to connect to [123:27017]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-red

I am trying to connect to Mongodb from Node Red and its showing the below Error..

```
Error: failed to connect to [123:27017]
```

I checked my password and it's working fine from command line and able to perform operations. Below is the Mongodb configuration file parameters.

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27017

-# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
 # noauth = true

auth = true
```

Can anybody suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: where is the 123 coming from?  the connect-to message is referring to a [host:port], and 123 is not a valid host.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have entered "123" as your Host for mongoDB.

I just did a quick test for connecting to "127" as host in my local Node-RED flow, and saw this error.

[error] [mongodb out:cd232f6a.63efc8] Error: failed to connect to [127:27017]

So update your host in your flow, and you should be able to connect to MongoDB.